# jquery.ui.datepicker 's Month select didn't working in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, internet-explorer-9

First of all , the browser is IE 9.

Two scripts are

```
   jquery.blockUI.js
   ui.datepicker.js
```

When I display the datepicker in normal page all things work well,

but when i try to display the datepicker in the popup page , the Month and Year Dropdown didn't work any more.

waiting for your reply!

Comment: Any chance you can reproduce in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/GaD3N/ . waiting for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use blockUI for this purpose. The blockUI plugin causes all input to be blocked on the screen so it makes sense why you can't "click" on the drop downs.

You should be using the [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) widget instead. For example:

```js
$('#btnTest').click(function() {
    $('#divAddNew').dialog({
        modal: true
    });
});
```